# chmod -R +rx on RHEL 7.2 doesn't set permissions

Tags: linux, rhel7, chmod

We have an odd problem on some of our RHEL Server 7.2 VM's:

Executing `sudo chmod -R +rx` doesn't change the read/directory flags for any of subdirectories. However, executing `sudo chmod -R a+rx` works just fine. e.g. for the *java-agent* folder below:

```
ls -la appdynamics/

drwxr-xr-x  4 appdynamics appdynamics   43 May  6 03:54 .
drwxr-xr-x. 8 root        root        4096 May  5 16:56 ..
drwx------  3 root        root          30 May  5 16:56 java-agent
drwxr-xr-x  3 root        root          17 May  6 03:54 machine-agent

sudo chmod -R +rx appdynamics 
ls -la appdynamics

drwxr-xr-x  4 appdynamics appdynamics   43 May  6 03:54 .
drwxr-xr-x. 8 root        root        4096 May  5 16:56 ..
drwx------  3 root        root          30 May  5 16:56 java-agent
drwxr-xr-x  3 root        root          17 May  6 03:54 machine-agent

sudo chmod -R a+rx appdynamics 
ls -la appdynamics

drwxr-xr-x  4 appdynamics appdynamics   43 May  6 03:54 .
drwxr-xr-x. 8 root        root        4096 May  5 16:56 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root        root          30 May  5 16:56 java-agent
drwxr-xr-x  3 root        root          17 May  6 03:54 machine-agent
```

As I understand it `chmod +rx` defaults to `a+rx` - but just not on some of our boxes, and only on RHEL 7.2 (6.8 seems to be fine).

I've never seen this before and googling doesn't seem to give any hints. It's a problem because it breaks existing chef cookbooks, but only for a handful of machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chmod +rx` and `chmod a+rx` isn't the same thing. The former honors the `umask` setting (i.e. won't set bits present in `umask`), while the latter is not. It seems your `umask` is set to `0077`, or something similar.